# Common docker compose items as yaml fragments

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I want to clean up my `docker-compose.yml` with yaml [fragments](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/10-fragments/).

```yaml
x-common: &common
  restart: unless-stopped
  security_opt: 
    - no-new-privileges:true
  volumes:
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro

services:

  myapp1:
    <<: *common
    image: app1
    volumes:
      - ./foo:/foo

  myapp2:
    <<: *common
    image: app2
    volumes:
      - ./bar:/bar
```

When I run `docker compose config` to show the final result, the common `restart` and `security_opt` items are applied. But the common `volumes` item is not - I assume this is because the services are overwriting it.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not really a great way to do this. The complicating factor is that `volumes` is a *list*, rather than a dictionary, and YAML doesn't have a syntax for merging lists.

You could do something like this:

```yaml
x-common: &common
  restart: unless-stopped
  security_opt: 
    - no-new-privileges:true

x-common-volume: &volume /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro

services:

  myapp1:
    <<: *common
    image: app1
    volumes:
      - *volume
      - ./foo:/foo

  myapp2:
    <<: *common
    image: app2
    volumes:
      - *volume
      - ./bar:/bar
```

Which gets you halfway there -- you need to remember to add the common volume to each service, but you don't have to retype the full entry each time.

---

Depending on how much this bothers you, you could look into generating your `docker-compose.yml` files with some sort of templating mechanism -- e.g., using [jsonnet](https://jsonnet.org/):

```
local Common = {
  restart: 'unless-stopped',
  security_opt: ['no-new-privileges:true'],
  volumes: [
    '/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro',
  ]
};

{
  services: {
    myapp1: Common {
      image: 'app1',
      volumes+: [
        './foo:/foo',
      ],
    },
    myapp2: Common {
      image: 'app2',
      volumes+: [
        './bar:/bar',
      ],
    },
  },
}
```

Generating your `docker-compose.yml` by running `jsonnet docker-compose.jsonnet > docker-compose.yaml` and you've got what you want.